# How to organize Objects using an Integer parameter

Tags: java, list, arraylist

Say I have an Object composed of a `String` and an `Integer`. How would I make an `ArrayList<Object>` with the objects with the highest integer value first and lowest last?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting.

Answer (score 1):

You could sort them with a customer `Comparator` based on that property. With Java 8's enhancements, it should be pretty elegant:

```
myList.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(MyObject::getIntegerProperty).reversed());
```